# Нужно вытащить названия столбцов из одного столбца

Tags: select, case

Есть таблица с двумя атрибутами HEADER и BODY.
Там строки вида:

| HEADER | BODY |
| --- | --- |
| Attr1,Attr2,Attr3 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |

Хочу получить результат в виде:

| Attr1 | Attr2 | Attr3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

То что сам пробовал не привожу, т.к. совсем не получилось.

Comment: Внимательно читаем [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим у вас Oracle.
Уже на этапе вывода динамического количества столбцов будет проблема.
Только PIVOT может добавлять столбцы, но они должны быть заранее перечислены:

```
with 
    my_table as (
        select
            'Attr1,Attr2,Attr3' as HEADER,
            '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' as BODY
        from DUAL
    ),
    my_columns as (
        select
            regexp_substr(t.HEADER, '[^,]+', 1, level) as ATTR_COLUMN
        from my_table t
        connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(t.HEADER, '[^,]+')) + 1
    )
select *
from (
    select *
    from my_columns
) pivot (
    count(ATTR_COLUMN)
    for (ATTR_COLUMN) in ('Attr1','Attr2','Attr3')
);
```

Скорее всего, нет способа без динамического запроса.